# Change class after changing list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

[image]I have a dual list in which data is printing a `ul li` pattern from a JSON file. You can move any `li` to any side list. I am stuck at a point.

I want to enable a property that the `<p>` tag content only in `<li>` in right-list gets `display: block` and not the left-list side `<li>`. I have tried different JS code but they didn't work for me .

```js
$('.content').hide();

$('.listelement').on('click', function() {
  if (!($(this).children('.content').is(':visible'))) {
    $('.content').slideUp();
    $(this).children('.content').slideDown();
  } else {
    $('.content').slideUp();
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.show', function() {
    css("display", "block");
  });
  
  $('body').on('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  
  $('.listarrows button').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this),
      actives = '';
    if ($button.hasClass('move-left')) {
      actives = $('.list-right ul li.active');
      actives.clone().appendTo('.list-left ul');
      actives.remove();
    } else if ($button.hasClass('move-right')) {
      actives = $('.list-left ul li.active');
      actives.clone().appendTo('.list-right ul');
      actives.remove();
    }
  });

  $('[name="SearchDualList"]').keyup(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == '9') return;
    if (code == '27') $(this).val(null);
    var $rows = $(this).closest('.dual-list').find('.list-group li');
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
  });
});

$(function() {
  var ctList = [];
  var ctRight = [];
  var $tBody = $("#La");
  var $rbody = $("#accordian");

  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/d6n2a', function(data) {
    data.topic_info.qt_ct_connection.map(value => {
      value.ct_list.forEach(CTLIST => {
        $tBody.append(`<li class="list-group-item" id="rl">${CTLIST.ct}<p style="display: none" class="show">
          <a href="#demo_${CTLIST.ct}" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
          <div id="demo_${CTLIST.ct}" class="collapse">
            ${CTLIST.tts}, ${CTLIST.topic_level}, ${CTLIST.to_be_shown_individually}, ${CTLIST.check_for_geometry}
          </div>        
        </p>
        </li>`);
      });
    })
  })
})
```

```css
 

.ctList {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .ctList .dual-list .list-group {
        margin-top: 8px;
    }

    .ctList .list-left li,
    .list-right li {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .ctList .list-arrows {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .ctList .list-arrows button {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="ctList">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="dual-list list-left col-md-5">
        <div class="well text-right">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                  <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 20px;"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" name="SearchDualList" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-default selector" title="select all">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group" id="La"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-arrows col-md-1 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-left">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-right">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="dual-list list-right col-md-5">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-default selector" title="select all">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="SearchDualList" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
                <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form>
            <ul class="list-group" id="accordian">
              <!-- right list  -->
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: can you add screenshot of your result and what are you expecting

Comment: I dont have one working code . But the thing is when you run this code and click the right list all the <p> tag in left tag also get property display:block. But i only want to add this property block to whenver any li is added in right list

Comment: Not specific to your issue:  If you do `$(existing element).appendTo()` it moves the existing element, so it's (essentially) the same as `$().clone().appendTo(); $().remove()`

Comment: Are you getting an error on this line: `css("display", "block");`?  Looks like it needs a context.

Comment: No not any error. But i want only right list to have display block property not the left-list li. i Have shared and image you can see.

Comment: When i click on right-list <a> all the p tag changes css. I want the right side content to change <p> display none to block

Comment: Is there a list on right side?? why i am not be able to see.

Comment: Maybe the css of snippet is not working ? I have shared an image you can see there

Comment: Hey, can you please write down full and clean code so, it's easy to more understandable.

Comment: I have adeed BS cdn maybe this make it easy to view

Comment: i added code, please have a look. and do let me know It's work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add CSS and remove inline style display none from p tag in JS.

```js
$('.content').hide();

$('.listelement').on('click', function() {
  if (!($(this).children('.content').is(':visible'))) {
    $('.content').slideUp();
    $(this).children('.content').slideDown();
  } else {
    $('.content').slideUp();
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.show', function() {
    css("display", "block");
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

  $('.listarrows button').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this),
      actives = '';
    if ($button.hasClass('move-left')) {
      actives = $('.list-right ul li.active');
      actives.clone().appendTo('.list-left ul');
      actives.remove();
    } else if ($button.hasClass('move-right')) {
      actives = $('.list-left ul li.active');
      actives.clone().appendTo('.list-right ul');
      actives.remove();
    }
  });

  $('[name="SearchDualList"]').keyup(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == '9') return;
    if (code == '27') $(this).val(null);
    var $rows = $(this).closest('.dual-list').find('.list-group li');
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
  });
});

$(function() {
  var ctList = [];
  var ctRight = [];
  var $tBody = $("#La");
  var $rbody = $("#accordian");

  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/d6n2a', function(data) {
    data.topic_info.qt_ct_connection.map(value => {
      value.ct_list.forEach(CTLIST => {
        $tBody.append(`<li class="list-group-item" id="rl">${CTLIST.ct}<p>
          <a href="#demo_${CTLIST.ct}" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
          <div id="demo_${CTLIST.ct}" class="collapse">
            ${CTLIST.tts}, ${CTLIST.topic_level}, ${CTLIST.to_be_shown_individually}, ${CTLIST.check_for_geometry}
          </div>        
        </p>
        </li>`);
      });
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.ctList {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.ctList .dual-list .list-group {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.ctList .list-left li,
.list-right li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ctList .list-arrows {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.ctList .list-arrows button {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/********************************/
/********************************/
/********************************/

/* ADD THIS */


.dual-list.list-left .well li.list-group-item p {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="ctList">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="dual-list list-left col-6">
        <div class="well text-right">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                  <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 20px;"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" name="SearchDualList" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-default selector" title="select all">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group" id="La"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dual-list list-right col-6">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-default selector" title="select all">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="SearchDualList" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
                <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <ul class="list-group" id="La">
            <li class="list-group-item" id="rl">point_in_first_quad
              <p>
                <a href="#demo_point_in_first_quad" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
              </p>
              <div id="demo_point_in_first_quad" class="collapse">
                10, capable, true, true
              </div>
              <p></p>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="rl">point_in_second_quad
              <p>
                <a href="#demo_point_in_second_quad" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
              </p>
              <div id="demo_point_in_second_quad" class="collapse">
                10, capable, true, true
              </div>
              <p></p>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="rl">trapezium_draw_slope_area_equ
              <p>
                <a href="#demo_trapezium_draw_slope_area_equ" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
              </p>
              <div id="demo_trapezium_draw_slope_area_equ" class="collapse">
                20, strong, true, true
              </div>
              <p></p>
            </li>
          </ul>


          <form>
            <ul class="list-group" id="accordian">
              <!-- right list  -->
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes it solved the problem. Can you just see a bug i noticed that if i move <li> from right to left list then any other item from left-right the prvious moved item from right-left also adds automatically. Can you help with this

Comment: Yes, i will help but i didn't get your question exactly. share screenshot or video

Comment: Ok i will , but what i wanted to say is every item moved right->left on any further movement of any item from left->right bring previous item also with it to the right side

Comment: ok, i got your point. For this i can't help you bro, because i don't know JS so much. I can only help you in HTML and CSS

Comment: You can add another question.